# Open an xAPI package and show previously completed percentage and complete slides ticked

Tags: c#, tin-can-api, xapi

Following on from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62752731/open-xapi-package-at-the-point-where-the-user-left-off/62756434#62756434) where I asked how to start an xAPI package at the point where a user left off (and kindly answered by @brian-j-miller) it has become apparent that I need something slightly different.

The client has asked that, on launching a previously opened packaged, we start at slide 1 (easy) but also show the completed slides on the left with a completed tick along with the percent complete.

Currently I use the state api to log to a custom table so I have access to the package slide Id's, percent complete, actor, all the things I think I would need to achieve this, what I'm missing is what to do with it to make the package show the correct thing on launch.  Eg, do I need to add something to the url?

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking about the URL. Just as you can store documents to the State API, you would retrieve them in nearly the same manner, so you should be able to retrieve the state as it was at the last exit (where you'd need to save it). How you represent that captured State is entirely up to you and outside the scope of xAPI.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks again